# Function php Clean up pasted text in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Function php Clean up pasted text in WordPress, dos not clean data

This script works amazing,

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init','configure_tinymce');

/**
 * Customize TinyMCE's configuration
 *
 * @param   array
 * @return  array
 */
function configure_tinymce($in) {
  $in['paste_preprocess'] = "function(plugin, args){
    // Strip all HTML tags except those we have whitelisted
    var whitelist = 'p,span,b,strong,i,em,h3,h4,h5,h6,ul,li,ol';
    var stripped = jQuery('<div>' + args.content + '</div>');
    var els = stripped.find('*').not(whitelist);
    for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var e = els[i];
      jQuery(e).replaceWith(e.innerHTML);
    }
    // Strip all class and id attributes
    stripped.find('*').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class');
    // Return the clean HTML
    args.content = stripped.html();
  }";
  return $in;
}
```

Code is from this [website](https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2015/02/19/clean-pasted-text-in-wordpress/)

but how to clean data in HTML tags =  exemple

```
<h4 data-uw-styling-context="true">» title</h4>
```

any ideas on how also to clean data information the same way?

Answer (score 0):

so i came up with the solution myself
very simple one just need to add what type of data needs to be removed **data-uw-styling-context**

```
stripped.find('*').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').removeAttr('data-uw-styling-context');
```